# Printing c3.js chart without messing up functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, c3.js

I have the following c3.js chart:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rvnLah4/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('chart')" value="Print Chart"/>
<script>
 function printDiv(divName){
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
 }
</script>
```

Chart:

```
blankData=[
  ['data1',0,0,0,0],
  ['data2',0,0,0,0],
  ['data3',0,0,0,0]
]

chartData=[
  ['data1',60,10,4,25],
  ['data2',30,22,5,30],
  ['data3',30,9,4,17]
]

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    size: {
        height: 500,
    },
    data: {
        columns: blankData,
        colors:{
          data1:'#00af50',
          data2:'#F7931E',
          data3: '#FF0000'
        },
        names:{
          data1:'namedata1',
          data2:'namedata2',
          data3:'namedata3'

        },

        type:'bar',

        labels: true,
    },



    tooltip: {
        show: false
    },    
    legend: {
        show: false
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['001', '002','003','004'],
             tick: {

             format: function (d) { 
              return "" ; }
            }
        }        
    },
    transition: {
      duration: 2000
    }
});
setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load ({columns: chartData});
 }, 500)
```

The "print chart" button that I've implemented does the following:

- saves the original page's HTML
- saves the HTML of just the chart
- sets the page's HTML to the chart's HTML (so only the chart is shown on the page)
- prints out the page (so effectively printing out just the chart)
- sets the page's HTML back to its original HTML

This works fine, however, my graph is no longer "dynamic" in a sense.  Notice that before printing, you can hover over the bars of the graph and they would change opacity.  After printing, though, the graph is more or less a pure HTML image of what it once was.  How can I re-implement my printing function to make sure my graph is kept "alive"?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Put everything into a different window or a seperate div and print that and discard it, leaving the original alone

Comment: You could use the CSS `@media print { ... }`.

Comment: was your print clean as it is seen in html ? I am trying to print it as well

Comment: @Sandeep Yep, it was. I'll post an answer with what logic I ended up using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering what ended up working the best for me:

I just ended up having the print button open up a popup window, copy the div object of the chart into the popup window, and auto-launch the print dialog. I also had the button close the popup window once the print was finished.